# Resetting the primary key to 1 after deleting all the data

Tags: mysql, primary-key

So i have MySql and i have a table user with a user_id column and it is the primary key and auto incremented. Now when i delete all my data from the table and add the new one, the user_id does not start from 1 but from the number it had before deletion. What if i want to reset it without dropping the whole table and creating it again.

Comment: Did my answer help you? and answer your question?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

So `some_table` would be the table you want to alter.

You could also use:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE some_table
```

This will reset the Auto Increment on the table as well as deleting all records from that table.

Answer (score 4):

The code below is best if you have some data in the database already but want to reset the user_id to 1 without deleting the data. Copy and run in SQL command

```
ALTER TABLE members DROP user_id;
ALTER TABLE members AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE members ADD user_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DBCC check identity to reset your Primary key.
here is the Sytax:

DBCC CHECKIDENT(TableName,RESEED,0)