# Insert new data to table after delete old data in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I delete all of old data. After that I want insert new data that the first new data I insert start with no.1 .
How I can do that.

Comment: An id is just an id, the value should not matter!

Comment: Read about triggers.

Comment: instead of using delete statement use truncate and then perform insert.

Comment: go into mysql table operation and set the auto increment value to 1

Comment: This question has been answered previously check this link.
[Resetting the primary key to 1 after deleting all the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972275/resetting-the-primary-key-to-1-after-deleting-all-the-data)

Comment: @rahul, SQL Server is tagged, not MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh oh my bad , i m sorry

Comment: The same query work in mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRUNCATE TABLE tblName` to remove all the data in a table.
Then insert your new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using DELETE FROM instead of TRUNCATE for some reason, you can reseed the Identity afterwards. The following Statement will lead to the next inserted line to get the identity-value 1.
`DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[Table_1]', reseed, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `delete` use `Truncate table <tablename>`.

This will reset your clustered index and new entry will start with 1 or whatever you define.

http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-delete-statement.htm

[What's the difference between TRUNCATE and DELETE in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139630/whats-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql)