# How can i reset my id counter to 1 in phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

So, I have a database with `10` users in it in which each one of them has an id from `1` to `10`. If I delete those `10` users from the database and then create a new user, the new user will start with the id of `11` and not `1`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting the primary key to 1 after deleting all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972275/resetting-the-primary-key-to-1-after-deleting-all-the-data)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651867/mysql-delete-all-rows-from-table-and-reset-id-to-zero

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `DELETE` statment (which will keep your `auto incrementing` indexes, and start them from the last `INSERTED` index) use `TRUNCATE`

```
TRUNCATE TABLE database_name.table_name;
```

[TRUNCATE REFERENCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html)

> Any AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to its start value. This is true even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence values.